# Deploy ionic 2 application to android device using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, ionic2

I have made simple app in ionic2 using visual studio. I have searched alot in google but not finding any clue how can I deploy this application for any android device?

Comment: Just push F5 to run the app and it will be deployed.

Comment: @FabioCampinho I said I want to deploy it in android device. Not in emulator

Comment: There is a Dropdown near the play/start button, change it to android device and then press F5.

Comment: @FabioCampinho I wanto build it's apk

Comment: There is no change from Ionic1 to Ionic2, you can get more information here: http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/

Comment: See about [ionic cli](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/) You will find the answer